# How to check if sheet exist?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to check whether given sheet (by name or number) exists in the file (xls 
or xlsx) before I read it. I am using Event API to address memory footprint 
issue and thus I don't want to use org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook object.

I am using Apache POI 3.7 with JDK7. Can someone please help me?

Thanks,

Parag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to check using the UserModel code is the same for the two formats.

However, you've asked about the Event API. These are much lower level, so the differences between the two formats have to be handled by you as there's nothing in between to hide them. (If you want an easy life, just buy some more memory for your server and stick with the UserModel!)

For the .xls file format (HSSF), the details of the sheets are stored near the top of the file. Start processing the file, and wait for the *BoundSheetRecord* (sid=0x0085) to come past. When you've seen all of those, you'll know if your sheet is in the file or not. If it is, process as normal. If not, abort.

For the .xlsx file format (XSSF), open the file and grab the workbook part (it's fairly small). Check that for what sheets exist, then decide based on that if you want to process or not. If you're using XSSFReader, call `getWorkbookData()` to get the Workbook part, then probably use XmlBeans to process it (via `WorkbookDocument.Factory`)

Comment: I got Workbook part using getWorkbookData(), but how to process it using XmlBeans to check if sheet exist or not? Can you please help with example? That will be really helpful, as this is the last thing I need...

Comment: Look at the source for [XSSFWorkbook](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.java) for an example, but it's basically `WorkbookDocument doc = WorkbookDocument.Factory.parse(inputStream);`

Comment: It's a long time but this answer helped me a lot.
But how to access the sheet state with the xlsb format ? I've run into a lot of issues.